# Animate words width with jQuery in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, transition

I'm having an jQuery issue, which is making my life hard.

So what I have done until now if this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zihiturofu/edit?html,css,js,output)

On what you can see, is that I am pretty close. What I need to achieve is to show words within a sentence, once one word is shown show the next one. Until a sentence has no words with a width of 0. Once that has happened the sentence hides, and the next sentence starts. Once all words in the last sentence are visible, everything starts over (infinite loop). But there has also to be the functionality of delays between words, and between sentences. I'm somehow not making progress right now with the code, so I thought I ask if someone had a similar issue, or if there is an plugin out there that could save my life.

How it should work is the following;

1. The words have to animate (as they are now)
2. Once one word appears, the next one is called
3. Once all words in one sentence have appeared, the sentence hides. Then the next word starts appearing which is in sentence two.
4. Some words have to have a delay meaning they should start appearing after the delay given
5. Also I should be able to set intervals between sentences.
6. Once the second sentence is done, it should hide. And everything should start again.

Thanks a lot for any kind of assistance.

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question and format it.  Questions where the relevant code is only in an off-site link are not appropriate here because the offsite resources tend to disappear or get changed over time rendering the question not very useful as a reference to those that come later.  It's also off-topic here to ask for a third party plug-in.

Comment: Which part of this specification are you asking for help with.  The jsbin seems to be running much of it already.  Please be specific about exactly what you're asking for help with.  Just posting a big chunk of code and a multi-step specification is not a specific enough question for stack overflow.

Comment: I am sorry for this, I will do my next questions with the guide you provided. My current problem is the delay on words that needs to work, before starting to show the next word. Somehow animate() complete is not being triggered at the end of the animation but at the beginning.

Comment: Please use the edit link to fix your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code below, should solve your problem. I have added some more properties (data attributes), so it is a little more dynamic.

```js
var sentences = $('.sentence');
var maxSentenceIndex = sentences.length - 1;
var currentSentenceIndex = 0;
var currentSentence = null;

var wordClass = '.word-row';
var standardDelay = 0;
var animationDuration = 1500;
var currentWordIndex = 0;

function loadSentence() {

  currentWordIndex = 0;
  currentSentence = sentences.eq(currentSentenceIndex);

  if (currentSentenceIndex > maxSentenceIndex) {

    currentSentenceIndex = 0;



  } else {
    currentSentenceIndex++;
  }
  currentSentence.show();
  loadWord();

}

function loadWord() {

  var $sentenceWords = $(currentSentence).find(wordClass);

  var maxWordsIndex = $sentenceWords.length - 1;


  animateWords($sentenceWords.eq(currentWordIndex));

  if (currentWordIndex > maxWordsIndex) {

    $sentenceWords.css('width', 0);
    $(currentSentence).hide();

    loadSentence();

  } else {
    currentWordIndex++;
  }

}

function animateWords(word, callback) {
  var $word = $(word);
  var delay = $(word).data('delay') || standardDelay;
  var width = $(word).data('width') || '100%';
  var speed = $(word).data('speed') || animationDuration;

  $word.animate({
    width: width
  }, {
    duration: speed,

    complete: function() {

      if (typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        setTimeout(callback, delay);
      } else {
        setTimeout(loadWord, delay);
      }

    }
  });


}
loadSentence();
```

```css
.element{
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    width: 120px;
    height: 600px;
    padding-top: 50pxs
}
.word-row{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
.word{
  display: block;
  width: 108px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="element typed-strings">
                


                <div class="sentence sentence-1">
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word">First word</span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word">Second word</span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word"><strong>auto</strong></span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word">strong</span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word">super</span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word">mario</span></div>
                </div>    

            
                <div class="sentence sentence-2">
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word"><strong>hello</strong></span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word"><strong>how is.</strong></span></div>
                    <div class="word-row" data-delay="1400"><span class="word"><strong>life</strong></span></div>
                    <div class="word-row"><span class="word"><strong>GREAT.</strong></span></div>
                </div>



                
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this works for you.